# Ajax, json in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I am trying to use the $http.get API to get a json data and then use it in my HTML tags.
I seem to miss something in the concept. here is my javascript:

```
var CouponsApp = angular.module('CouponsController', []);

CouponsApp.controller("CellCouponController", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('CouponsJSON.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="CellTable" ng-controller="CouponController">
    <p> Cell Phones Coupons</p>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Cell Image</th>
            <th>Manufacturer Url</th>
            <th>Local Vendor</th>
            <th>Local Vendor Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="coupon in coupons">
            <td>{{CellPhones.model}}</td>
            <td>{{CellPhones.manufacturer}}</td>
            <td>
                <img src="{{CellPhones.CellImage}}" alt="{{CellPhones.CellPhones}}"          width="50px;" height="50px;" width="60px">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{CellPhones.manufacturerUrl}}"> {{CellPhones.manufacturer}} URL   </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{CellPhones.localVendor}}</td>
            <td>{{CellPhones.localVendorAddress}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to get the json data, insert it to an object and then parse it in the ng-repeat?

Comment: You are defining a module with angular.module('CouponsController', []); not a controller.  It should be angular.module('app', []). Then in your HTML, <div ng-app="app">

Answer (score 0):

You must define a $scope.coupons = {}; in your controller , and then attach your get data to that like this :

```
     controller:

        $scope.coupons = {};

        $http.get('CouponsJSON.json')
        .success(function(data){
         // first console.log(data) it to check getting data is correctly working : 
         console.log(data);
         $scope.coupons.coupon =  data;
         // its good practice to always use a DOT!!
        }) 

     Now in your html you can use ng-repeat like this : 

      <div ng-repeat="coup in coupons.coupon">
          {{coup}}
      </div>
```